# What type should I use to indicate an argument is a filename in C#?

Tags: c#, arguments

My functions needs a file name so it can read and/or write to this file.
I could use a simple string for this purpose

```
void myFunc(string filename)
```

but I'd rather have some more type-safety by requiring a more specialized type and not detect that `""` is no valid filename within the method.

The class `File` doesn't work because it's static.

The class `FileInfo` could be used but I cannot remember that I've come across a filename argument of this type.

In personal projects I made up my own class that simply does some checking if the filename is well-formed etc. so e.g. an exception is thrown upon creation of the filename and not in the method itself.

Since the new project is of wider scope I'd thought it would be better to use a common standard to not confuse other users (or my future self in some weeks).

Comment: Why can't you just use File.Exists to see if the file is there?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user3444160 If the method requires a file and a user passes something else that fit's into a string, I'd rather have the exception _before_ calling the method. It's also a clear statement and harder to misuse accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking about `FileInfo` was correct - its only constructor has a fileName argument, and it performs basic validation for you. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public FileInfo(string fileName)
```

Comment: you could also add the documentation comments to the function.  If they are using Visual Studio they can type /// on the line before to generate documentation (this will also get picked up in intelli-sense)

Comment: Would you personally expect you have to provide a filename if the argument's type is `FileInfo` and that the file will be read/written? Although it's a standard type, I get the feeling I would be misusing it for another purpose...

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding FileInfo insufficient for some reason, you may be dealing with the file name in a manner that more closely matches a [System.Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri(v=vs.110).aspx). A Uri is not necessarily always related to a file, but a file path can be an example of a Uri, and Microsoft's implementation supports this with the IsFile property. One could imagine a FileUri class which inherits from Uri and IsFile is forced.

*It is probably worth mentioning that in most of the MSDN snippets I've been looking at, file paths and names are just passed as strings. This may just be for convenience though.*

Comment: That file (path)s are represented as strings is also what I discovered. I suppose it's mainly for historical reasons.